# How to grant full permission for authenticated users for a folder with powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to grant to the builtin authenticated user group access to my folder. After running my script i can see that the authenticated users has been added as a new entry in the security tab of the folder, but full controll has not been set.

[image]

Here is my script

```
$local=Get-WinSystemLocale

$acl = get-acl C:\ProgramData\foo\bar
if ($local.Name.StartsWith("de")){
    Write-Host "deutsches System"
    $ace = new-object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('authentifizierte Benutzer','FullControl','Allow')
}
elseif ($local.Name.StartsWith("en")){
    Write-Host "englisches System"
    $ace = new-object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('Authenticated Users','FullControl','Allow')
}
elseif ($local.Name.StartsWith("fr")){
    Write-Host "französisches System"
    $ace = new-object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('Authenticated Users','FullControl','Allow')
}

$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
$acl | Set-Acl
```

By the way is there a better way to distinguish between the names for the authenticated users group? I solved it with examine the name of the system locale and then i can decide how the group is named. Currently I do not know the french translation.

Comment: For the second part of your question, try this: `$sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-11");$user = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value`,  This returns _"NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"_ on my English system - hopefully it will return the appropriate name on non-English systems.

Comment: Thanks, on my german system it works as well. Now its only left why the full controll is not granted

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the `Authenticated Users` by way of the `WellKnownSidType` enumeration.
Probably also, you need a different constructor, where you can set the [Inheritance and Propagation flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_AccessControl_FileSystemAccessRule__ctor_System_Security_Principal_IdentityReference_System_Security_AccessControl_FileSystemRights_System_Security_AccessControl_InheritanceFlags_System_Security_AccessControl_PropagationFlags_System_Security_AccessControl_AccessControlType_)

Something like this:

```
$path = 'C:\ProgramData\foo\bar'
$acl  = Get-Acl -Path $path

$user = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier' -ArgumentList @([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::AuthenticatedUserSid, $null)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user, 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

Hope this helps